# Как добавить метабокс на страницу редактирования медиафайла?

Tags: wordpress

Хочу добавить метабокс на страницу редактирования медиафайла, вроде вышло, но не до конца.

То есть когда мы находимся в галерее с отображением картинок сеткой, если щелкнуть по картинке то выйдет окно как на первом скрине. Вот именно туда я хочу засунуть свой метаблкс.

А у меня получилось его засунуть только когда уже перешли на полное редактирование этой картинки(второй скрин).

Добавил метабокс вот так:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cover_field', 1 );
function cover_field() {
    add_meta_box( 'attachment_fields_thumbnail', 'Обложка для альбома', 'attachment_fields_thumbnail', 'attachment', 'side', 'low' );
}
```

В общем есть ли варианты засунуть мой метабокс на окошко в первом скрине?

[image: Скрин1]
[image: скрин2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На странице `/wp-admin/upload.php?item=xxxx` (первый скрин) метабоксы не работают и действие `add_meta_boxes` не вызывается. поэтому ваша функция ничего не выводит.

Всё, что вы можете сделать - добавить свой input в виде html-кода на эту страницу с помощью

```
add_action( 'print_media_templates', 'print_media_templates_action' );
```

и потом обрабатывать произведённые там действия через ajax.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, это то что нужно!